# cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getactivity() from the type fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static, android-context

I am trying to resresh my map after user interaction.In my project there is a class such that :

```
public  class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

private long lastTouched = 0;
private static final long SCROLL_TIME = 200L;
private UpdateMapAfterUserInterection updateMapAfterUserInterection;

public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {


    super(context);
    // Force the host activity to implement the UpdateMapAfterUserInterection Interface
    try {

        updateMapAfterUserInterection = (StationsFragment.getActivity()) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement UpdateMapAfterUserInterection");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        lastTouched = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (now - lastTouched > SCROLL_TIME) {
            // Update the map
            updateMapAfterUserInterection.onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Map Activity must implement this interface
public interface UpdateMapAfterUserInterection {
    public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection();
}
```

}

My StationsFragment Class includes and refreshes the map.But in the TouchableWrapper Class at this line

```
updateMapAfterUserInterection = (StationsFragment.getActivity()) context;
```

gives an error "cannot make a static reference the non-static method getactivity() from the type fragment".When I change the Class type of StationsFragment Fragment to FragmentActivity and change the code like this:

```
  updateMapAfterUserInterection = (StationsFragment) context;
```

It works.But I need Fragment Class.How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use following line..

```
use updateMapAfterUserInterection = (UpdateMapAfterUserInterection) context;
```

implement `UpdateMapAfterUserInterection` interface in your required fragment.

Comment: Thans for your answer.But TouchableWrapper Class is not an activity.So GetActivity is useless.

Comment: sorry didn't gone through your code at intially and given answer from your last few lines of question..     check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are implementing `UpdateMapAfterUserInterection` interface in `StationsFragment` class then pass `this` from `StationsFragment` to Class object  to `UpdateMapAfterUserInterection` as:

```
 public TouchableWrapper(Context context,StationsFragment objStationsFragment) {

    super(context);
    updateMapAfterUserInterection = 
               (UpdateMapAfterUserInterection) objStationsFragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to instantiate your `TouchableWrapper`, you need in any case a `context` object, due of `TouchableWrapper(Context context)`. If the context you provided to the constructor, is the one of the activity that hosts your `Fragment`, you can safely  cast the context to the `Activity`'s object, if this activity is implementing that `StationsFragment` interface